# Matching list of #define to a pattern

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have an header with a lot of `#define`s, like this:

```
#define XY_ABC_FOO 1
#define XY_ABC_BAR 3
#define XY_ABC_PIPPO 5
#define XY_ABC_PLUTO 7
#define XY_ABC_ETC 19
...
```

and so on and on.

I'd like to put all those in a vector.I can do it by hand (in a few minutes).

```
std::vector<int> defs = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 19 , ... }
```

But then, next time definition are added in the header, someone will have to remember to add them in my code too.

Is there any very clever preprocessor/metaprogramming trick to catch them all at compile time? 
I don't particularly care about fast compilation, it's test code so it will be compiled seldom and mostly overnight.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, it got published by mistake while I was writing. Now it's complete.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you wanna add all the `#defines` into a vector?

Comment: Is an enum of values acceptable, or do they have to be macros?

Comment: The header isn't under my control, and they chose macros.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do it in C++ or the preprocessor, but you could do it with an `awk` script.

Comment: @BatCoder yes, I want to have a vector containing all the values of defines matching a given pattern.

Comment: Since C++ doesn't have any introspection capabilities, you're out of luck within pure C++. If you controlled the definitions, you could extract the names and values into something reusable, but even then, you can't `#define` things in the middle of iterating over such a list.

Comment: @Barmar that could get the job done, although it's not what I hoped for. Maybe I can automate inside VisualStudio running awk before the compilation starts? As long as all needed files are versioned in the SVN...

Comment: Since you mention Visual Studio, I would recommend design-time [text templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with `awk`:

```
awk '/^#define XY_ABC_\w+ \d+$/ { 
    if(line) {
        line = line ", " $2
    } else {
        line = "std::vector<int> defs = { " $2
    }
    END { print line " };" }' < header.hpp > defs.hpp
```

Then in your main program use `#include defs.hpp` to get the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to achieve that using only `#define`s, but I'm almost completely sure that it's impossible.

But if you'd allow those values to be `constexpr`s, then you'd be able to do following. (And it's probably a best thing you can get without external tools.)

```
#define DEFS \
    C(XY_ABC_FOO,    1) \
    C(XY_ABC_BAR,    3) \
    C(XY_ABC_PIPPO,  5) \
    C(XY_ABC_PLUTO,  7) \
    C(XY_ABC_ETC,   19)

#define C(name, value) constexpr int name = value;
DEFS 
#undef C

/* ... */

#define C(name, value) value,
std::vector<int> defs = {DEFS};
#undef C
```

Comment: He said he can't change the original header file.

Comment: The answer is still potentially useful to future visitors who do have control over the definitions.